# Simple NumPy array reference

Tags: python, numpy

I am having issues understanding how `X` and `y` are referenced for training.

I have a simple `csv` file with 5 numeric columns that I am loading into a `NumPy` array as follows:

```
url = "http://www.xyz/shortDataFinal.data"
# download the file
raw_data = urllib.urlopen(url)
# load the CSV file as a numpy matrix
dataset = np.loadtxt(raw_data, delimiter=",")
print(dataset.shape)
# separate the data from the target attributes

X = dataset[:,0:3] #Does this mean columns 1-4?
y = dataset[:,4] #Is this the 5th column?
```

I think I am referencing my `X` values incorrectly.

Here is what I need:

`X` values reference columns 1-4 and my `y` value is the last column, which is the 5th. If I understand correctly, I should be referencing array indices `0:3` for the `X` values and number 4 for the `y` as I have done above. However, those  values aren't correct. In other words, the values returned by the array don't match the values in the data - they are off by one column (index).

Comment: You want `0:4` (to get 4 columns).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your interpretation is correct. `dataset` is a matrix in this case, so the numpy indexing operators (`[]`) use the conventional row, column format.

`X = dataset[:,0:3]` is interpreted as "All rows for columns 0 through 3" and `y = dataset[:,4]` is interpreted as "all rows for column 4".

Answer (score 1):

Using a multiline string as a standin for a csv file:

```
In [332]: txt=b"""0, 1, 2, 4, 5
   .....: 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
   .....: """

In [333]: data=np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=',')

In [334]: data
Out[334]: 
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   4.,   5.],
       [  6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.]])

In [335]: data.shape
Out[335]: (2, 5)

In [336]: data[:,0:4]
Out[336]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  4.],
       [ 6.,  7.,  8.,  9.]])

In [337]: data[:,4]
Out[337]: array([  5.,  10.])
```

`numpy` indexing starts at 0; [0:4] is the same (more or less) as the list of numbers starting at 0, up to, but not including 4.

```
In [339]: np.arange(0,4)
Out[339]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Another way to get all but the last column is to use `-1` indexing

```
In [352]: data[:,:-1]
Out[352]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  4.],
       [ 6.,  7.,  8.,  9.]])
```

Often a CSV file is a mix of numeric and string values. The `loadtxt` `dtype` parameter has a short explanation of how you can load and access that as a structured array.  `genfromtxt` is easier to use for that (though no less confusing).